# SQl Stored Procedure not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a stored procedure that wont run properly:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `visitor_search`(
IN _startDate datetime,
IN _endDate datetime,
IN _visitorName text,
IN _personToVisit text
)
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM visitor
where
logged_in >= _startDate
and logged_in <= _endDate
and concat(firstname, "", lastname) like('%' + _visitorName + '%')
and person_to_visit like('%' + _personToVisit + '%')
order by logged_in desc;
END
```

I think it is the following lines that are acting up.

```
and concat(firstname, "", lastname) like('%' + _visitorName + '%')
and person_to_visit like('%' + _personToVisit + '%')
```

Is this correct syntax?

Regards,

Bob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `CONCAT()` there too.

```
and concat(firstname, "", lastname) like concat('%', _visitorName, '%')
and person_to_visit like concat('%', _personToVisit, '%')
```

and don't forget to use a different delimiter.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `visitor_search`(
IN _startDate datetime,
IN _endDate datetime,
IN _visitorName text,
IN _personToVisit text
)
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM visitor
where
logged_in >= _startDate
and logged_in <= _endDate
and concat(firstname, "", lastname) like concat('%', _visitorName, '%')
and person_to_visit like concat('%', _personToVisit, '%')
order by logged_in desc;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I was about to write that as well +1

Answer (score 0):

try this perhaps:

```
and concat(firstname, "", lastname) like concat('%' , _visitorName , '%')
and person_to_visit like concat('%' , _personToVisit , '%')
```

LIKE is not a function

Comment: Sorry, saw the other comment first weirdly enough. But yes, this is the correct solution! Thanks!