# How to Set ouput of select in variable by mysql?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

i want to count product id set to variable @x. in query of phpmyadmin no procedure or function.
but error

```
set @x=70489;
    set @y = select count(`product_id`) from `oc_product` where  `language_id`=2 and `product_id`=@x;

    select @x;
    SELECT @y;
```

> SQL query: Documentation
>   set @x=70489
>   set @y = select count(`product_id`) from `oc_product` where  `language_id`=2 and `product_id`=@x;
>   MySQL said: Documentation
>   1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'set @y = select count(`product_id`) from `oc_product` where  `langua' at line 2

Comment: You're missing a `;` in the very first line.

Comment: know but not work

Comment: Set a different delimiter?

Comment: delimiter? edit my code?

Comment: set @z=2;
if(@z<=2) then
set @x=70489;
end if
select @X;

Comment: An example can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25481744/sql-stored-procedure-not-working/25481789#25481789 A different delimiter is necessary, so that the first `;` doesn't end the procedure/function declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**add () in start and end of select.**

```
set @x=70489;
set @y = (select COUNT(*) from `oc_product` where  `language_id`=2 and `product_id`= @x);

SELECT @x;
SELECT @y;
```